# Getting custom annotations (Ti.Map) pixelated

Tags: titanium, appcelerator-mobile

I've tried with different images in several resolutions (50x30, 70x50, 100x70). All of them are good enough out of titanium app, but I cannot get custom pins without pixel effect into the app.

I'm using Titatnium 3.0.

How can I make my custom images to obtain a best visual result?

Images source: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DogVj.jpg

Code:

```
var annot = Titanium.Map.createAnnotation({
    longitude : franchise.direction.loc[0],
    latitude : franchise.direction.loc[1],
    title : franchise.name,
    subtitle : franchise.direction.address,
    image : "testing_pin.png",
    animate : false,
    draggable : false
});                 
$.mapView.addAnnotation(annot);
```

Comment: Any code to show? Any images to show? Otherwise any answers are pure speculation.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I've already updated the question with further details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the Pin icon sizes I use, and they look sharp on my maps.

pin@2x.png: 80px x 80px @72 dpi

pin.png: 40px x 40px

Comment: Exactly! It works like a charm! I hadn't added the @2x image. Thanks!